# FreePascal: How to create a list of objects

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

So I have the following code and I want to create a list of different food that is saved in the class TRoom.

```
Food = class  
  durability : Integer;  
end;

TRoom = class
  Food_list : ???
end;
```

Example:
sleeping: TRoom
and in "sleeping" is an apple and a banana both are objects.

Thanks for your help
Nuraxx

Comment: You can use [generic object list](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Generics) (specialized for your abstract `Food` class, e.g. `TFPGObjectList<Food>`).

Comment: In trunk you can also use the delphi compatible tobjectlist<>